# Using Trigger to keep data integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, linked-server

I have scoured the internet for a solution (mostly scouring stack overflow) and I cannot come up with anything.

Here is my goal: I have a local database and I have set up a linked server to another database. I am creating a trigger on one of my local tables. One of the column values is a Hotel ID. In the linked server there is a table called "Hotel". The point of this trigger is to check and make sure that the HotelID I am trying to insert into my local table is a value that exists in the linked server's Hotel table.

Example: If I want to insert a new row into my "Store Table" from local, I want to make sure that the HotelID I am trying to insert exists in the "Hotel" table in my linked server. If it does not exist, I want to rollback the transaction and display a message.

Below is the code I have been playing with. I feel like I could be close, but I am open to the idea that I am extremely far away.

FYI: The code inside of the IF NOT EXISTS statement is incorrect. I am just confused as to what needs to go in there.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_trigger ON Store
AFTER Insert
AS
DECLARE @HotelID smallint = (SELECT HotelID FROM inserted)

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT   * FROM OPENQUERY (test,''               
SELECT HotelID FROM test.dbo.Hotel WHERE HotelID = ''''' +   
CONVERT(nvarchar(15),@HotelID) +''''''')'
DECLARE @StoredResult Nvarchar(20)
BEGIN
EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@StoredResult NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @StoredResult =  
@StoredResult OUTPUT
SELECT @StoredResult

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (test,' SELECT HotelID FROM test.dbo.Hotel'))
BEGIN
    PRINT'That HotelID does not exist. Please try again.'

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

END
GO
```

EDIT: This has been solved thanks to a couple of suggestions from marc_s. Below is my new code that works how I need it to.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_trigger ON Store
AFTER Update, Insert
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT A.* FROM OPENQUERY (test, 'SELECT HotelID  FROM test.dbo.hotel') A
        INNER JOIN inserted i
        ON A.HotelID = i.HotelID)
    BEGIN
        PRINT'Please enter a valid HotelID'     
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END 
END
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT HotelID FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: This is an after insert trigger. I could easily remove update and it will still function as I am asking it to. The point of this is to see if the HotelID I am trying to insert exists in the linked server table, and if it does not, rollback the insert and display an error. Update is irrelevant and I am removing it as we speak. And also, Select hotelid from inserted only selects the HotelID I am trying to insert into the "Store Table". It selects nothing else.

Comment: I hope that clears a couple of things up. I hope I'm explaining this properly.

Comment: You're **still** assuming to get only a single row - this is ***NOT*** the case! The `Inserted` table *can* (and *will*!) contain multiple rows - and you're just using one arbitrary one of those to do your checks. You need to **completely re-architect** your trigger to handle **multiple rows** in `Inserted` !

Comment: If that is the case then I am clueless. It has worked for several of my SPROCS/UDFS/Triggers. Maybe I just got lucky. I am very open to ideas though.. Do you have any suggestions that can push me towards my end goal?

Comment: Also, right now when I run an INSERT statement on my "Store Table", the current output with the code as it stands using the below insert statement: 
    INSERT INTO STORE
    VALUES('Test',2100)

    Is: 2100
Which is the value I am hoping for as the value 2100 exists. If I instead do:
INSERT INTO STORE
VALUES('Test',6000)
Nothing is returned because the value does not exist.

Comment: I would just join your `Inserted` pseudo table with your `FARMS_Prescott.dbo.Hotel` on the `HotelID` and see if you get the same number of rows back as are present in the `Inserted` table. If not, then at least one of the inserted hotels doesn't exist and your trigger has to fail the whole insert

Comment: Actually marc_s... I for some reason didn't follow you until I created the query to test the values. Once I realized that joining the inserted table is what I needed, I just moved that query I whipped up inside of my IF NOT EXISTS statement and it now works perfectly. I will add an edit above that includes my new working code. How do I mark one of your questions as answered? I am new to stack overflow (as far as owning an account)

Comment: If you try inserting two rows in the one operation, one good and one bad, does it behave the way you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_DataIntegrity ON Store
AFTER Update, Insert
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM inserted i 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT A.*
               FROM OPENQUERY (TITAN_Prescott_Store, 'SELECT HotelID  FROM FARMS_Prescott.dbo.hotel') A
                WHERE A.HotelID = i.HotelID))
         BEGIN
             PRINT'Please do not enter an invalid HotelID'     
             ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         END 
END
GO
```

Comment: The thing with this is that if you insert several rows and any of them are invalid, it will rollback.

Comment: That is an excellent point. For the purpose of this trigger that doesn't matter, but that is something that is definitely good to keep in mind.